in TUS Java client how do I set the transfer length when I don't know it beforehand
I'm using TUS Java client (io.tus.java.client.Tusupload) to upload a large (several giga bytes) file using tus protocol to my server which is based on me.desair.tus.server.TusFileUploadService.
On the client side I can do:
            TusUpload upload = new TusUpload();
            upload.setSize(filelength);

And that works if I know the filelength, which I don't as the file is generated on the fly.
In the TUS protocol spec it says that I can set the size to 1 initially and once I know that I can then set the size to the correct value.
I have tried this but once I call upload.setSize(1) calling it again has no effect, the server side always sees 1.
If I leave the initial call to setSize() away then I get an exception on the server side as it is a protocol violation to have no size.
Setting the correct size is vital because the size together with the number of bytes received on the server side is what marks the end of the upload and now my code never realised that the whole file has been transferred.
A related question is how can I determine at the server side if the client has died and will never complete upload. I guess that as this is an HTTP REST style protocol all I can do is to have timeout for the transfer.

That's confusing. If the file has not yet been created, why don't you wait until it has been?

@g00se Why would you store several gigabytes, if you can just stream them?

@Sören I wouldn't. But the file apparently already exists or is required to exist. If that's wrong in some way, then an InputStream should probably be used with the API.

@g00se OP writes "And that works if I know the filelength, which I don't as the file is generated on the fly."

Then either a. Don't generate it and use a stream, or b. generate it and wait until it is generated. It has to be said that an uploading API that needs an upload size to be set is badly designed. What would be legitimate is a max upload size.

The file is directory of hundreds of  files tar'd and gzip'd on the fly. As there is a lot of data it makes no sense to copy data around neither at the client or server which is what happens if the tar.gzip file is generated before hand.

@nyholku Please [edit] your question to include a [mcve] for the client and for the server part. Include the code which updates the size on the client side while uploading the data. Also include the server code, where you try to read the size.

At this point it is pointless to produce test case as I've looked into the source code and I don't think the tus client support deferred length, at least I saw no evidence of it.
